# thread exiting with uncaught exception (no error but forcly stopping)

Tags: java, android, eclipse

My JAVA Class:

```
package com.example.myprojectname;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Data extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

Button start, startFor;
EditText sendET;
TextView gotAnswer;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.get);
    initialize();
    }

private void initialize() {

    start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSA); 
    startFor = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSAFR);
    sendET = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etSend);
    gotAnswer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvGot);

    start.setOnClickListener(this);
    startFor.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (arg0.getId()){
    case R.id.bSA:
        String bread = sendET.getText().toString();
        Bundle basket = new Bundle();
        basket.putString("key", bread);
            Intent a = new Intent (Data.this, OpenedClass.class);
        a.putExtras(basket);
        startActivity(a);
        break;
    case R.id.bSAFR:
        break;
    }
    }

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
if (resultCode == RESULT_OK){
    Bundle basket = data.getExtras();
    String s = basket.getString("answer");
    gotAnswer.setText(s);
}
}







}
```

my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
 >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etSend"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   >


</EditText>

<Button
    android:layout_below="@id/etSend"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:id="@+id/bSA"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="StartActivity" />

<Button
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/bSA"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/bSA"
    android:id="@+id/bSAFR"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="StartActivityResult" />

<TextView
    android:layout_below="@id/bSAFR"
    android:id="@+id/tvGot"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView" />

</RelativeLayout>``
```

and my problem LOGCAT:

```
    11-14 15:58:46.177: D/AndroidRuntime(277): Shutting down VM
    11-14 15:58:46.177: W/dalvikvm(277): threadid=1: thread exiting with                           (group=0x4001d800)
    11-14 15:58:46.197: E/AndroidRuntime(277): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    11-14 15:58:46.197: E/AndroidRuntime(277): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to     find explicit activity class {com.example.myprojectname/com.example.myprojectname.Data};     have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
    11-14 15:58:46.197: E/AndroidRuntime(277):  at   android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1404)
    11-14 15:58:46.197: E/AndroidRuntime(277):  at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1378)
    11-14 15:58:46.197: E/AndroidRuntime(277):  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:2817)
    11-14 15:58:46.197: E/AndroidRuntime(277):  at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:2923)
    11-14 15:58:46.197: E/AndroidRuntime(277):  at com.example.myprojectname.Menu.onListItemClick(Menu.java:35)
    11-14 15:58:46.197: E/AndroidRuntime(277):  at android.app.ListActivity$2.onItemClick(ListActivity.java:321)
    11-14 15:58:46.197: E/AndroidRuntime(277):  at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:284)
    11-14 15:58:46.197: E/AndroidRuntime(277):  at android.widget.ListView.performItemClick(ListView.java:3382)
    11-14 15:58:46.197: E/AndroidRuntime(277):  at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:1696)
    11-14 15:58:46.197: E/AndroidRuntime(277):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
    11-14 15:58:46.197: E/AndroidRuntime(277):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    11-14 15:58:46.197: E/AndroidRuntime(277):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
    11-14 15:58:46.197: E/AndroidRuntime(277):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
    11-14 15:58:46.197: E/AndroidRuntime(277):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    11-14 15:58:46.197: E/AndroidRuntime(277):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
    11-14 15:58:46.197: E/AndroidRuntime(277):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
    11-14 15:58:46.197: E/AndroidRuntime(277):  at     com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
        11-14 15:58:46.197: E/AndroidRuntime(277):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: check if you have made an entry for the activity in manifest file

Answer (score 3):

Straight from logcat :

```
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.myprojectname/com.example.myprojectname.Data}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
```

You need to declare your activity in your manifest.

---

***Advice of the day :*** Read the logcat messages, they are often very informative and will save you a lot of time.

Answer (score 1):

I Guess you forgot to specify this activity in manifest.

Try to specify that in manifest

Answer (score 1):

add this to the manifest under application tag:

```
<activity
        android:name="com.example.simplebrowser.Data"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.DEFAULT" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add `Data` as `Activity` in your Manifest.
Please to to `AndroidManifest.xml` file and within ` tag add following lines:

```
<activity
        android:name=".Data"
        android:label="activity name" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: you're welcome Sir. Please don't forget to mark the answer that helped you as a corrent solution ;)